# Find string in list - Erlang

Tags: string, list, erlang

I am trying to find if some string is really in list. There is my code:

```
comparing() ->
    FileName = "msg-0001",
    {ok,[NumLine],_} = io_lib:fread("msg-~d",FileName),
    io:format("Numline:~p~n", [NumLine]),
    {ok, Pars} = file:read_file("parsing.txt"),
    {ok, Dump} = file:read_file("msg-0001"),
    StringNumline = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [NumLine])),
    io:format("StringNumline:~p~n", [StringNumline]),
    StringDump = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Dump])),
    io:format("StringDump:~p~n", [StringDump]),
    SubStringDump = string:substr(StringDump, 4),
    io:format("SubStringDump:~p~n", [SubStringDump]),
    Ndump = concat(StringNumline, SubStringDump),
    io:format("Ndump:~p~n", [Ndump]),
    FineDump = Ndump--"\">>",
    io:format("FineDump:~p~n", [FineDump]),
    L1 = binary:split(Pars, <<"\r\n">>, [global]),
    io:format("L1=~p~n", [L1]),
    Check = lists:member(FineDump, L1),
    io:format("Check=~p~n", [Check]),

    if
        Check ->
            file:write_file("check.txt", "true\n", [append]);

        true ->
            file:write_file("check.txt", "false\n", [append])
    end.
```

Here is output of the code:

```
10> c(compare).         
{ok,compare}
11> compare:comparing().
Numline:1
StringNumline:"1"
StringDump:"<<\"hello\">>"
SubStringDump:"hello\">>"
Ndump:"1hello\">>"
FineDump:"1hello"
L1=[<<"0hello">>,<<"something">>,<<"anyword">>,<<"1hello">>,<<"2exercise">>,
    <<"2solution">>,<<"3test">>,<<"new">>,<<"4check">>,<<"4grade">>]
Check=false
ok
```

I have a problem in line `Check = lists:member(FineDump, L1)`. It's always false although 1hello is member of the list. I don't know where is the mistake. Is it function lists:member fine for this operation? Or does exist some other way to find if string is a member of a list? I'm new at Erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L1` is a list of binaries while `FineDump` is a string (a list of integers in Erlang). You need to convert `FineDump` into a binary to make the `lists:member/2` call work.

This should work:

```
Check = lists:member(list_to_binary(FineDump), L1),
```

You also seem to be doing this in a way too convoluted way than necessary. If I understood the logic fine, you don't need all that code. You can concatenate `NumLine` and `Dump` into a binary using just:

```
X = <<(integer_to_binary(NumLine))/binary, Dump/binary>>
```

and then use that directly in `lists:member`:

```
lists:member(X, L1)
```

```
1> NumLine = 1.
1
2> Dump = <<"hello">>.
<<"hello">>
3> <<(integer_to_binary(NumLine))/binary, Dump/binary>>.
<<"1hello">>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. You don't need to do all this `string:substr` and `io:format` stuff (which is also incorrect if the binary contains double quotes or angle brackets) just to concatenate an integer and binary.

Comment: Great solution, I was trying a lot of ways to write my code, so I did on this, compicated way. It was worked, so I was satisfied with it. But your way is much better. Thanks a lot :)